# How to do that one Jenkins job waits when another job will be ended?

Tags: jenkins, automation

I try to find solution to my Jenkins task. 
I am begginer in Jenkins, so I hope you can help me.

We have two jobs **A** and **B**.

Job A is triggered, then it is in progress and during it I trigger job B. 
I want to temporarily hang job A, to wait until job B will be end (because I will use result files of job B in job A), and then continue it job A.
Any ideas how I can do it?

Any prompts/solution?
Big thanks in advance